# Using filters in Angular

Tags: angular, filter, server

so here i am with a new question. I'm trying to use filters in Angular but i can't get how to let server and client communicating each other.

Here is the code:

SHOWCASE.COMPONENT.TS

```
export class ShowcaseComponent implements OnInit {

  products: ProductDTO[];
  filter: FilterConfig[] = [];

  
  nameFilter(filter: string) { return this.products.filter(product => product.Name.toLowerCase()) }
   descriptionFilter(filter: string) { return this.products.filter(product => product.Description.toLowerCase()) }
   categoryFilter(filter: string) { return this.products.filter(product => product.Category) }


  
  filtersSelected(event) {
debugger
if (this.filtersSelected == null) {
  return;
}
  }


  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private http: HttpClient) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {}


    let nameFilter: FilterConfig = FilterConfig.CreateStandardFilterConfig("NAME_FILTER", "Nome", "Name", InputType.Text, WherePartType.Equal);
    this.filter.push(nameFilter);

    let descriptionFilter: FilterConfig = FilterConfig.CreateStandardFilterConfig("DESCRIPTION_FILTER", "Descrizione", "Description", InputType.Text, WherePartType.Equal);
    this.filter.push(descriptionFilter);

    let categoryFilter: FilterConfig = FilterConfig.CreateStandardFilterConfig("CATEGORY_FILTER", "Categoria", "Category", InputType.Text, WherePartType.Equal);
    this.filter.push(categoryFilter);
  }
```